# Migrating preferences to AndroidX

Tags: java, android, androidx

I'm trying to migrate my old auto-generated (from the activity gallery in Android Studio) settings activity to `AndroidX`. Unfortunately, I can't find any info on how to do that. The official docs aren't very helpful, since they assume you already have all the code in place to add your preference fragments and `XML`.

I tried switching the old `PreferenceScreen` to the `AndroidX` one, and `PreferenceFragment` to `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, but that only results in a runtime exception.

Does anyone know how to perform such migration?

Comment: Make sure you add this implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'. Are you using java or kotlin?

Comment: I'm using Java and the dependency is added.

Comment: oops! sorry, I don't have any java reference, But I use PreferenceFragmentCompat in kotlin almost every project. Can you share error

Comment: `android.preference.PreferenceActivity.switchToHeaderInner()` throws `android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class xxx.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment that is not a Fragment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question - it's not worth migrating existing preference activity. It's faster to make an empty one and manually set fragments, as in the docs. Everything seems to be working in such case, and most of previous code is unused.

Answer (score 1):

I had to migrate an existing project to AndroidX.

So I just switched to `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

To give you an idea here is some example code:

Java:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends
        androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat implements
        androidx.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener,
        androidx.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
       // ... your code
}
```

xml:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="@string/PREF_SCR_MAIN">

    <androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:key="@string/PREF_CAT_MAIN"
        android:title="@string/pref_cat_main">

        <androidx.preference.CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="@string/TOUCH_TWICE_TO_EXIT"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sum_touch_twice_to_exit"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_touch_twice_to_exit" />

    </androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to the **Refactor** option in the ribbon of Android Studio. Then click Migrate to `AndroidX`.

Also, add these two lines in `build.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

These lines will force the classes which aren't moved to `AndroidX` to migrate while migrating.

**Note**: Please backup your Project when prompted! If you don't know much about AndroidX, please backup your project and then try it!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not migrate preferences.